# Custom integrity constraint in flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Ok, I need direction, please.

I've got a roles database with values such as admin, staff, manager, user

And a user table with a role_id FK.

I'm using Flask and Sqlalchemy.

I want to achieve a scenario where there can only be one super admin while other users can have other roles assigned. This means if the super admin role is 2, on the users' table, there can only be one entry for role_id 2.

What do I need to achieve this in sqlalchemy.

Update with code

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]="sqlite:////tmp/stack.db"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "roles"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.role

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    # what to add to role_id to make it have only one superadmin role id in this table
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id', onupdate='CASCADE'))
    role = db.relationship('User')
```

If I've got in the roles table

```
| id  |  name      |
|-----|------------|
| 1   | superadmin |
| 2   | admin      |
| 3   | staff      |
```

I want there to be only one superadmin in the User's table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]="sqlite:////tmp/stack.db"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Roles(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "roles"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    role = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.role

db.create_all()
```

If I were you I would do this.
I would then insert the roles manually.

If you create another table say users, you will reference the roles from the above table.

I believe this will solve your problem.